# How to Change Setup Project Version

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-setup-proje

I have a Setup project that I built a while ago in VS2010 and have recently ported that project into VS2013.

I installed the [Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d) extension and my Setup project compiled fine.

However, I cannot figure out how to change the version of my Setup project without manually changing the `.vdproj` file. In other words, in VS2010, I was able to go to a Properties page of the Setup project and change the version there - and VS would respond with a warning that I should change the GUID of the project as well. - That feature is no longer in this new extension that I can find.

How do I change the Setup project version in the new `Visual Studio Installer Project` extension?

Answer (score 11):

Select the Setup project in `Solution Explorer`, then click the `F4` function key. The `Properties` page will open up.

Comment: Strangely "right click" and Properties has a whole different behaviour.

Comment: @MichaelFayad it still happens on VS 2022. Weird...

Comment: I figured out a little quirk in VS2022.  Highlight your install project.  Instead of selecting properties from the context menu (right click menu), select the vertical Properties tab on the side of the Visual Studio Window.  That shows a completely different properties page.

Answer (score 0):

Here is VS2022 solution:

Highlight your install project in the Solution Explorer:

[image]

Click on the Properties tab on the side bar:

[image]

That should give you important properties like version and others that are hard to find:

[image]

NOTE: If you don't have the side bar properties showing . . .

[image]

Right click one of your Project Output Objects and that will create the tab and open that objects properties. Then select your install project in the Solution Explorer again.  The properties tab will be there.  You can now toggle it as long as you don't X it out when the properties page is open.

[image]